# Validates uniqueness com uma exceção

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-record, model-validation

Bom dia,

Sou iniciante no Rails e estou com o seguinte problema:

Preciso fazer uma validação no meu model onde o conteúdo precisa ser único exceto quando for '000000'.

Eu já tentei usar:

```
validates :registration, uniqueness: true, exclusion: {in: '000000'}
validates :registration, uniqueness: true, unless: {in: '000000'}
end
```

Alguém conseguiria me ajudar a fazer esta validação funcionar?

Answer (score 0):

Uma possível solução seria criar um método de validação (que deve retornar true ou false) e chamá-lo na clausula unless do validates:

```
    validates :registration, uniqueness: true, unless: :registration_equals_zero

   def registration_equals_zero
     registration == '000000'
   end
```

Fiz o teste aqui, utilizando o Rails 6.1

Mais informações: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation